# expression to get different return type in java lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I  am having a map which stores a key as a character and value as an method call.
when I get the value from the map the particular method gets invoked.

```
Map<Character, IntUnaryOperator> commands = new HashMap<>();
commands.put('a', number -> funtion1(number) );
commands.put('b', number -> funtion1(number) );

char cmd = 'a';
IntUnaryOperator result=  commands.get(cmd);

System.out.println(" Return value is "+result.applyAsInt(101));
```

Where function1 is as follows,

```
public static int funtion1(int number){
    System.out.println("hello");
    return number;
}
```

How can I modify the source code to return an string type or any other type?

Comment: Change `IntUnaryOperator` to whatever [other functional interface type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/package-summary.html) suits your needs, perhaps `UnaryOperator<String>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `IntUnaryOperator` will take `int` and result `int`
- `UnaryOperator<T>` will take `T` and result `T` (`IntUnaryOperator` is `UnaryOperator<Integer>`)
- `Function<T,R>`  will take `T` and result `R` (`UnaryOperator<T>` is `Function<T,T>`)

So you need `Function<Integer,String>` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Map<Character, Function<Integer, String>> commands = new HashMap<>();
    commands.put('a', Guitar::funtion1); // method reference
    commands.put('b', number -> funtion1(number));

    char cmd = 'a';
    Function<Integer, String> result = commands.get(cmd);                 // Function
    System.out.println("Return value is " + result.apply(55));            // 55 bar
    System.out.println("Return value is " + commands.get('b').apply(32)); // 32 bar
}

public static String funtion1(int text) {
    System.out.println("hello");
    return text + " bar";
}
```

- I also change one in `reference method` jusr for

Comment: Thank you, but I want to pass integer and return a string from the function.    Idea is to pass a different type from that of a return type. Over here we are passing string and getting string in return